# How to hide mat-checkbox from typescript file

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I need to hide the `mat-checkbox` control from `typescript` file based on tab selection getting changed in my application.

This is `html` file code

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="OnChangeRed($event)" id="check1" class="example-margin" [checked]="matCheckboxRed"></mat-checkbox>
```

Tabs in the same `html` file

```
<div>    
<mat-tab-group #tabRef (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged(tabRef.selectedIndex)">
  <mat-tab label="ALL"></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Actvie"></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Inactive"></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Deliverted"></mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>    
</div>
```

When my tab change calling I need to hide checkbox

```
tabChanged(index)
{

}
```

How can I do that

Comment: please share ur tabs implementation as well

Comment: @YogendraR - Please check my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ngModel with checkbox as follows:

```
<mat-checkbox *ngIf="show" (change)="OnChangeRed($event)" id="check1" class="example-margin" [checked]="matCheckboxRed"></mat-checkbox>
```

and in the tabChanged event you can change show value according to the tab that have been triggered:

```
show: boolean = true;

tabChanged(index)
{
   if(index == "your tab index"){
     this.show = false;
   }

}
```

Another approach using ViewChild:

```
<mat-checkbox #checkbox (change)="OnChangeRed($event)" id="check1" class="example-margin" [checked]="matCheckboxRed"></mat-checkbox>
```

and in ts file:

```
@ViewChild('checkbox') el:ElementRef;

    tabChanged(index)
    {
       if(index == "your tab index"){
     this.el.nativeElement.style.display='none';
       }
    }
```